# Change PATH for LIBS

Tags: c, 64-bit, cross-compiling, linker-errors, libs

I have recently been trying to compile dropbear for 64bit arch android devices. I got the program to compile and run, but when I log in to the server it kicks me off with an error.

I configured & compiled like so:

```
cp ../config.guess ../config.sub .
./configure --build=x86_64-windows --host=arm-linux-androideabi \
--disable-zlib --disable-largefile --disable-loginfunc \
--disable-shadow --disable-utmp --disable-utmpx --disable-wtmp \
--disable-wtmpx --disable-pututline --disable-pututxline --disable-lastlog \
CFLAGS='-Os -W -Wall -fPIE' LDFLAGS='-fPIE -pie'

make dropbear
```

The error:

```
CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE: "/system/lib/libc++.so" is 32-bit instead of 64-bit
page record for 0x7f800b8010 was not found (block_size=32)
```

I believe the error is caused by dropbear linking sh and other executables to the library in wrong location.

The device has two locations for libc++

```
  #1 /system/lib/libc++.so
  #2 /system/lib64/libc++.so
```

How can I tell/force the compiled binary to use the lib(s) in

```
/sytem/lib64
```

If giving an example please show me exactly what needs to be added, so I can apply the information correctly. I'm almost sure the fix is simple but I'm not a programmer. I do this stuff when I'm desperate.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out there was a hard link in srv-chansession.c that needed to be modified

From:

```
addnewvar("LD_LIBRARY_PATH", "/system/lib");
```

To:

```
addnewvar("LD_LIBRARY_PATH", "/system/lib64");
```

It may actually be better to comment out that line and let androids linkers take care of it.

Now I have working a working dropbear ssh server on my 64 bit android device.